# Customizing Flask-WTF or WTForms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to integrate Flask as the backend for the UI I'm working with.

Unfortunately the UI already has the CSS and JavaScript set up for the forms (to accommodate for the UI but also for older versions of IE and other cases).

The first problem that I'm running into is that there is already a label for the fields.  If I use the **.labels** attribute in the template:

```
{{ form.username.label }}
```

then it creates an extra label which I can't seem to add any attributes to for the CSS/JavaScript.  However if I leave the **.label** attribute off then it creates an extra blank text field above the username input.

The code in my **forms.py** file is:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Am I missing something on this?

The second part is adding attributes to the form itself.  I've found how to add the HTML **class** attribute using **class_='classname'**, but the Flask-WTF and WTForms documentation don't seem to touch on any other attributes (such as **autcomplete="off"** or **placholder="username"**)

Is there some way to accomplish this with Flask-WTF or WTForms that I'm just missing?  Am I limited to manual attributes and/or Jinja macros for this type of functionality?  I can't imagine this is something that would be missing form WTForms and Flask-WTF but I also don't see it mentioned anywhere in the docs or on Google/StackOverflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After happening on this [WTForms : How to add "autofocus" attribute to a StringField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969070/wtforms-how-to-add-autofocus-attribute-to-a-stringfield?rq=1) I tried to use the same approach to my problem.  And it worked.  Still not sure why this isn't covered in the WTForms or Flask-WTForms docs.

So for the labels, to have them contain the class, or other attributes you require, in the template add it the same as the **class_=** explanation above.

So in this case :

```
{{ form.username.label(class_="ie9") }}
```

adds the appropriate class to the label when rendered.

For the string inputs the attributes are again added in the template:

```
{{ form.username(class_="formplace", placeholder="Username", autocomplete="off", autofocus="true", size=32) }}
```

Renders with the proper HTML for class, placeholder, autocomplete, autofocus, and size in the field.

I'm sure this can be made dynamic and reusable, but just wanted to show the solution since I can't be the only person having this issue.  Specifically it was 0xTim's solution that lead me to something usable.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what @Andy Lance has said above, you can use `render_kw` in your flask forms. Say you have a `forms.py`:

```py
class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
    comment = TextAreaField('Comment', validators=[DataRequired()]) #<---------Add placeholder info
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

Modify the `TextAreaField` to include `render_kw`:

```py
class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
    comment = TextAreaField('Comment', validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Markdown Enabled"}) #<---------placeholder info added
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

You do not have to modify your templates do display the keywords. Maintain your template as (if using `flask-bootstrap`):

```py
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
```